# Python splitting text with line breaks into a list

Tags: python, regex, list

I'm trying to convert some text into a list. The text contains special characters, numbers, and line breaks. Ultimately I want to have a list with each word as an item in the list without any special characters, numbers, or spaces.

exerpt from text:

```
I have no ambition to lose my life on the post-road between St. Petersburgh and Archangel. &lt;the&lt I
```

Currently I'm using this line to split each word into an item in the list:

```py
text_list = [re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", ' ', k) \
   for k in content.split(" ")]
print(text_list)
```

This code is leaving in spaces and combining words in each item of the list like below

Result:

```
['I', 'have', 'no', 'ambition', 'to', 'lose', 'my', 'life', 'on', 'the',
 'post road', 'between St ', 'Petersburgh', 'and', 'Archangel ', ' lt the lt I']
```

I would like to split the words into individual items of the list and remove the string ' lt ' and numbers from my list items.

Expected result:

```
['I', 'have', 'no', 'ambition', 'to', 'lose', 'my', 'life', 'on', 'the',
 'post', 'road', 'between', 'St', 'Petersburgh', 'and', 'Archangel', 'the' 'I']
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: The result you provided as an example isn't actually the result you'll get when running the code. (and the second "lt" probably also had a ";")

Comment: I'm looking at the original text and yes it looks like this:  "&lt;the&lt;
I"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it looks like you're parsing html text, it's likely all entities are enclosed in `&` and `;`. Removing those makes matching the rest quite easy.

```py
import re

content = 'I have no ambition to lose my life on the post-road between St. Petersburgh and Archangel. &lt;the&lt; I'

# first, remove entities, the question mark makes sure the expression isn't too greedy
content = re.sub(r'&[^ ]+?;', '', content)
# then just match anything that meets your rules
text_list = re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z0-9]+", content)
print(text_list)
```

Note that `'St Petersburg'` likely got matched together because the character between the 't' and 'P' probably isn't a space, but a non-breaking space. If this were just html, I'd expect there to be `&nbsp;` or something of the sort, but it's possible that in your case there's some UTF non-breaking space character there.

That should not matter with the code above, but if you use a solution using `.split()`, it likely won't see that character as a space.

In case the `&lt` is not your mistake, but in the original, this works as a replacement for the `.sub()` statement:

```
content = re.sub(r'&[^ ;]+?(?=[ ;]);?', '', content)
```

Clearly a bit more complicated: it substitutes any string that starts with `&` [`&`], followed by one or more characters that are not a space or `;`, taking as little as possible [`[^ ;]+?`], but only if they are then followed by a space or a `;` [`(?=[ ;])`], and in that case that `;` is also matched [`;?`].

Comment: This is a great solution but at the end of the users expected output they don't have `lt`. Your output does.

Comment: It does not, if the content does indeed have `&lt;` instead of `&lt` (which is possibly a mistake in the example). But if it's not, I can add an example of how to match those as well.

Comment: Yeah, I also assumed it would be some kind of mistake on the OP's side. Just wanted to point it out. Good solution btw.

Comment: Thank you so much this works. I truly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what can can be done. You just need to replace any known code of syntax in advance

```py
import re

# define some special syntax that want to remove  
special_syntax = r"&(lt|nbsp|gt|amp|quot|apos|cent|pound|yen|euro|copy|reg|)[; ]"

text_list = [re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", ' ', k).strip() \
  # Here I remove the syntax before split them and substitue special char again
  for k in re.sub(special_syntax, ' ', content).split(" ")]
  
# remove empty string from the list
filter_object = filter(lambda x: x != "", text_list) 
list(filter_object)
```

Output

```
['I', 'have', 'no', 'ambition', 'to', 'lose', 'my', 'life', 'on', 'the',
 'post road', 'between', 'St', 'Petersburgh', 'and', 'Archangel', 'the', 'I']
```